# RPi3 B+ Stretch. Config for external capture device & onboard headphone jack

Tags: audio, raspbian-stretch, alsa

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I am planning to use an external Microphone "**ReSpeaker 4Mic Hat**" from Seeed-Studio on my RPi3 B+ Stretch OS. However, when I run **alsamixer**, my external Mic is not the default capture device. It seems like bcm2835 is the default soundcard, which means as default I don't have any capture device.

If I launch **audacity**, I can successfully record sound with the external microphone.

So, where I can set the default setting for Alsa like:

```
Default Input: "hw1,0", 
default output: "hw0,0"
```

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not resolved this, check here:
http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_4_Mic_Array_for_Raspberry_Pi/

It says:
"If we want to change the alsa settings, we can use sudo alsactl --file=ac108_asound.state store to save it. And when we need to use the settings again, copy it to: sudo cp ~/seeed-voicecard/ac108_asound.state /var/lib/alsa/asound.state"